# Does using 2 same Provider Consumer in one widget tree rebuild all different consumer value?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Im trying to build my app as good as possible using provider. If i put same consumer provider in one widget like this for example

```
   Column(
                children: [
                  Consumer<Provider1>(
                    builder: (context, value, child) {
                      return Text(value.text1);
                    },
                  ),
                  Consumer<Provider1>(
                    builder: (context, value, child) {
                      return Text(value.text2);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

if i update text1 value and notifylistener() does the text2 or the other widget with the same provider get rebuild too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,it does rebuild all consumers value.
You can use Selector for update only that widget like this

```
return Selector<Provider1, String>(
      builder: (context, text1, child) {
        return Text(text1);
      },
      selector: ((context, provider1) => provider1.text1),
    );
```

Comment: so this method will only update that selected value ? it won't affect the other selector with same provider?

Comment: Yes, it won't affect the other selector with the same provider

Comment: one more, you said "it does rebuild all consumers value" is it only for the same provider or all provider ?

Comment: No, it is only same provider